# Inversion array of a given array

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, data-structures, algorithm-analysis, arrays

Let A[1...n] be an array of n distinct numbers. The ordering of the numbers is any permutation of [1,2,...,n]. An array Inv_A is defined as follows: Inv_A[i] = number of elements A[j] such that j<i and A[j] > A[i]. Give an optimal algorithm that computes the above array Inv_A. For example if A = [3,1,4,5,2] then Inv_A = [0,1,0,0,3]. Expected time complexity is O(nlogn).

Comment: What have you tried? Hint 1: try altering merge sort to compute the thing. Hint 2: or try using segment trees to compute the thing.

Comment: What's your question?  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question about your situation.  We're not particularly looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this task?  Can you credit the original source?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

Apply [heap-sort](https://www.happycoders.eu/algorithms/heapsort/) for in-place sorting in $O(log(n))$ time. For a real application, it's better to use the simple randomized-quick-sort. You can get enough build-in routines in almost every popular language.